# Copy a jar file with maven

Tags: maven, ant, pom.xml

I'm trying to copy the .jar, created by Maven 3, to another location.
Currently, I'm using Ant's copy task, but Maven simply doesn't copy the file.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>install</phase>
      <configuration>
        <tasks>
          <copy file="target/myfile.jar" tofile="D:/Bukkit/plugins/myfile.jar"/>
        </tasks>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The question is why do you like to do that? Cause that looks that you are copying outside the current project which is *not* the intention of Maven. That looks more like a job for a deployment tool which Maven is *not*. Ant task is one way, but better solved outside from maven.

Comment: What tool would you suggest for that purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <copy file="target/myfile.jar" tofile="D:/Bukkit/plugins/myfile.jar"/>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```